# Convert MS access to MySQL DB using php

Tags: mysql, migration, ms-access

We are creating a system that has a button for converting MS Access DB to MySQL. Is there a way to convert MS Access DB to MySQL using PHP?

I would really appreciate any inputs on this one. Thank you in advance folks!

Comment: Why on earth would you use PHP for that purpose?  Did MS forget to provide a means to export the data from their DB?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-export.html

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I suspect they are providing conversion as a web-based service, where people upload their `mdb` file to the site and get back a MySQL-compatible `sql` file.

Comment: @Gerard H.Pile, Dario is correct, our users need that feature often that's why we would like to provide them a 3 step process rather than us doing that every other day since our end-users are not techie's.

Comment: Care to provide some info about your web server?  OS ...

Answer (score 1):

Use Workbench to migrate the data:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-access.html

Comment: this MS Access (not SQL Server) - not sure, is it will work at all?

Comment: @a_vlad - oops, wrong page.  Workbench will import many different flavors of dbs.

Comment: :) there are some other, like Navicat (expensive) or DBeaver free - https://dbeaver.io, in any case - it is one time task in most of case, so no reason do this as script - convert and forget